# (Ex 3.9 b, Lam) If $R$ is semisimple ring with $aR = I$ a two-side ideal, then prove that $Ra = I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

My approach: Suppose I know that $aR = R$; $a \in R$, $\implies Ra = R$ for a semisimple ring $R$

Now I think I can apply this result as follows. Since $I$ is an ideal in $R$, it can be considered as a ring in itself ($R = I \oplus U , \phi: R \rightarrow I$ a ring hom with kernel $U$) and we know that $a \in I$, therefore in the ring $I$, $aI = I$. Now using the above result that $aR = R \implies Ra =R$ , I conclude that $Ia = I$ and hence $I \subseteq Ra \subseteq R$. But $RaR = I$; since $aR = I$ and $Ra \subseteq RaR$ therefore $Ra = I$

But for some reason my proof doesn't seem convincing enough, so can somebody crosscheck it once again and provide solution (hint) if its wrong.

Comment: I'm not an expert on ring theory, but your "proof" doesn't convince me either. It feels lengthy and as you're using several assumptions (like $aR=R$).

Comment: $I$ is only a **rng**, i.e. ring without identity, and therefore $aI=I$ need not be true.

Comment: @Berci Every ideal in a semisimple ring is in fact a ring with identity. (Obvious from the ideal structure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a valid idea, but I think the last part is not very clear.

If $aR=I$ is an ideal, then it is immediate that $Ra\subseteq I$. It only remains to be shown that $I\subseteq Ra$.

From the lemma, $aI=I$ implies $I=Ia\subseteq Ra$ and you are done.

The lemma you suggested is easy to prove after all since $aR=R$ implies $a$ is right invertible, hence left invertible in a semisimple ring. This it is a unit and $Ra=R$ too.

Comment: The relation $Ra \subseteq I$ is immediate since $I$ is a *right-sided* ideal (which it is since it's two-sided).

Comment: @md2perpe I think you mean "left sided"